# C++ string cout error

Tags: c++

I have have this code, but it's not compiling correctly.  When I compile this code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string stringone;
    stringone = "abcdef";
    cout << stringone << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler tells me this error:

> error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: what does "not working correctly" mean?

Comment: This: error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Don't count on standard headers to include other standard headers.

Comment: This compiles fine in Xcode without #include <string>, FWIW.

Comment: @RyanTuck I wouldn't be surprised. Different compilers, different implementations of the "standard". It just depends where they've declared `operator<<`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `#include <string>` as well.

Comment: Oh, really? The book I'm using didn't mention that

Comment: @AmazingGrace Which book are you using?

Comment: @AmazingGrace, I would be cautious of the book then. Here's a list of some [good ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I have the C++ for Dummies

Comment: @AmazingGrace, Yeah, I haven't heard too much praise for that.

Comment: @AmazingGrace It's the thought that counts.

Comment: I'll probably return it and find another book to use

Comment: @chris I think the problem is that c++ is not for dummies

Comment: What book would you recommend?

Comment: @AmazingGrace, Pick one from my link that fits you.